# Ansible playbook hangs in interactive mode

Tags: ansible, cluster, interactive, redis, mode

If I run the command (`redis-cli --cluster create 192.168.1.10:6379 192.168.1.11:6379 192.168.1.15:6379`) from the host(192.168.1.10) it prompts me for "yes" and it's working but in ansible hangs forever. Is there any solution? Thanks

```yaml
- name: Create Redis cluster with master nodes
  command: "redis-cli --cluster create 192.168.1.10:6379 192.168.1.11:6379 192.168.1.15:6379"
  args:
    stdin: "yes"
  when:
    - inventory_hostname == groups['redis-master'][0]
```

Comment: See the [ansible `expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html). You could also very well use the [`--cluster-yes` option](https://redis.io/docs/manual/scaling/#scripting-a-resharding-operation) to answer yes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could

- use `--cluster-yes` option (... have a look into [redis: Create cluster with redis-cli non interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206257/))
- use the `shell` module and `echo "yes" |` followed by your command
- or use the `shell` module and the [`yes` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/)

**Further Readings**

- [Whats the difference between Ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/)